# Use multiple fonts in tcpdf

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I want to use multiple fonts in tcpdf..
ex: Hello world
I want Hello in frutiger light font and world in frutiger Bold

```
$fruit=$pdf->AddFont('fruit');
$pdf->SetFont($fruit['family']);
```

Everthing appears in frutiger light font.I dont know how to use multiple fonts .It would be great if someone answers.i have include this frutiger light and frutiger bold in my font library.Thanks in Advance

Comment: You call set font before you output text. i.e. SetFont('Font1'); Write('Hello'); SetFont('Font2'); Write('World'); + you will need to adjust positioning.

Comment: hello world is just an ex... it consists of huge tables where heading name has to be in bold

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Set bold font print table header set normal font print rest.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new font, you need to do that :

```
$pdf->addTTFfont('fontName', '', 'fontName.php');
$pdf->addTTFfont('fontNameBold', '', 'fontNameBold.php');
```

And to use both, you have to do like that :

```
$pdf->SetFont('fontName', '', 10);
//Write something here with the font "fontName"
$pdf->SetFont('fontNameBold', '', 10);
//Write something here in bold with the font "fontNameBold"
$pdf->SetFont('fontName', '', 15);
//Write something here with the font "fontName"
```

And if you don't have your answer now, you can check this one : http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Or this one : http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Answer (score 1):

```
 \TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath(_SITE_PATH_.'.../ARIALNB.TTF'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); // bold

$fontname = \TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(realpath(_SITE_PATH_.'.../ARIALN.TTF'), 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); // normal

$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 10, '', false); // set normal

// else $pdf->SetFont('ARIALN', '', 10, '', false); // set normal

$html='[ b ]Развъдна организация/[/b]/[br/] // format bold
[span  style="line-height: 11px;"]TEXT[/span]';

$pdf->writeHTMLCell(61, 25, 138, 7, $html, 0, 0, 0, true, 'L', true); // print
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.